# certificate SSL error 60: unable to get local issuer certificate with wamp 2.5 php5.5.12

Tags: php, ssl, curl, wamp, symfony

I had this problem for 2 days ago i have already google it and i found that the problem is the curl and a had download the carcet.pem file and change the php.ini.

I'm using the console to create a new symfony project but always having this error , `$ php symfony new project` in the folder that contains the symfony file...

Error :

```
  [GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException]
  cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate






  [GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\RingException]
  cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate



new <directory> [<version>]
```

if someone have any idea can help me to resolve it. Thunks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is similar question [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997669/curl-error-60-ssl-certification-issue-when-attempting-to-use-symfony) with an answer part of which (use `C:> composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name` instead of `C:> php symfony new blog`) works.