# cURL error 60: ssl certification issue when attempting to use symfony

Tags: php, symfony, exception, certificate

I have recently gotten a new windows computer and have installed the php symfony framework.

When attempting to use the new command `C:> php symfony new blog` I receive the error message `[GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\RingException] cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`.

I am clueless on what to do in this instance as I am not too experienced with the CMD interface.

I need to know if this is an error with windows or with symfony itself and any possible routes I could take in fixing it.

Comment: Hi colin both of @mokhtar-tlili suggestions work Please mark answer.

Comment: This answer may help you, even though it's about Wamp - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32095378/178163

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Follow [this](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) link, Copy the entire page and save it in a: "`cacert.pem`"

Then in your `php.ini` file insert or edit the following line: curl.cainfo = "[pathtothisfile]\cacert.pem"

Or

use [composer](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/installation.html#creating-symfony-applications-without-the-installer) instead Symfony installer

Comment: I tried copying the .pem page in and was unsuccessful but with symfony everything had turned out A OK!

Comment: Composer is better solution for installing the `Symfony`. Just use the command `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name "2.7.*"` and you can successfully installed the Symfony.

Comment: composer ended up working thank you! I'll be resulting to composer for most tasks for now on!

Comment: @kushalsuthar Your answer helped me finally "install" the damn thing. Where can a reference to that be found on their website, all I can see is some skeleton bull (create-project symfony/skeleton blabla I am not gonna work) that again does not work (your way is the only way that works for me) ?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error with the php version 7.0.10

The mistake I did was that I copyied the certificate `(cacert.pem)` in the wrong `php.ini` file. I mean, I have 3 type of ini file: `php-development.ini`, `php-production.ini` and `php.ini`

and the right one was `php.ini`

Make sure you put the path of the certificate in the right one.

And it will work ! ;)
lovely symfony <3

FH

Answer (score 3):

you can try the the command line below,it's worked for me

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name "2.8.*"
```