# How to solve error 60 ssl certificate for symfony

Tags: symfony, frameworks, certificate, php-5.5

I'm trying to install symfony 2, but when I copied the symfony.phar file and I tried to upload it with the cmd it wont work:

[image][image]

> C:\wamp\www>php symfony.phar new Symfony
>
> [GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException]
>     cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certific
>     ate
>
> [GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\RingException]
>     cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certific
>     ate
>
> new  []

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997669/curl-error-60-ssl-certification-issue-when-attempting-to-use-symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997669/curl-error-60-ssl-certification-issue-when-attempting-to-use-symfony)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a symfony problem, is related with your php Curl extension. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)