# Error when installing symfony3

Tags: wamp, symfony, php-5.6

I am tring to install symfony3 , I am using this link https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony/symfony-un-framework-php

when I am tring to create a new project this error appear                **curl: (60) SSL certificate : unable to get local issuer certificate**

so I have tried to resovle the problem by following those two solutions!

[curl: (60) SSL certificate : unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

**And**

https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/symfony-3-erreur-installation?page=2

but Always I have an error!!

the error now:

```
C:\wamp\www>php symfony.phar new Symfony

[GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException]
cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: C:/wamp/bin/php/cacert.pem
CApath: none


[GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\RingException]
cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: C:/wamp/bin/php/cacert.pem
CApath: none



new <directory> [<version>]
```

- How can I make it work?
- Also the cacert.pem file I have opened the link https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem  then right click save the file (the type of the file is .txt) is the type of file correct?

Comment: Save the file as `cacert.pem`, not `cacert.pem.txt`

Comment: @Veve but when I open the link above it will open the file cacert directly the only way is to save it "save as" and it's  automatically cacert.pem.txt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the file as `cacert.pem`, not `cacert.pem.txt`.

To do so, when you save the file, choose "All (*.*)" instead of "Text Document (*.txt)"  in the filetype under the filename in the save dialog.

[image]

Or if you already downloaded it as a txt file, open a command line in the folder `C:\wamp\bin\php\` then type this command to rename the file with its correct extension:

```
move cacert.pem.txt cacert.pem
```

Comment: I have just use the move command thank you very much it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

This question is already exist check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997669/curl-error-60-ssl-certification-issue-when-attempting-to-use-symfony/38002070#38002070)

If your issue still persist try to install Symfony using Composer instead Symfony Installer

**Step 1** 
- Install Composer Global: follow this [link](https://github.com/composer/windows-setup/releases/)

**Step 2**
- Install Symfony :

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition name_of_project 3.*
```